# OperationalError at /i18n/setlang/ when switching language

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'm new to python and django, I'm trying to set my website with 2 languages. When I switch the language with the form in base.html I receive this

> OperationalError at /i18n/setlang/
>   no such table: django_session

Settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale') 
]

LANGUAGES = [
    ('it', ('Italian')),
    ('en', ('English')),
]
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls')),
    path('about-us/', include('about.urls')),
]
```

base.html

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" >
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
               {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```